# Make a CodeModel object implement/inherit a parent, before Having it been saved as an actual class on disk

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I need to add an implementaion of an interface to a populated `JCodeModel` object, before saving it to a `.java` file using `codeModel.build("FilePath");`. I'm using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/) library to create `JCodeModel` object.

The code is this:

```
JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();

GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
    @Override
        public SourceType getSourceType() {
            return SourceType.JSON;
            }
        };

SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());

mapper.generate(codeModel, action, packageName, apiResultAsString);

codeModel.build(new File("src").getAbsoluteFile());
```

The `JCodeModel` has the option to implement Interface in a class ( `_implements()` ), But I can't utilize it in the above code (refer to the comments below in the code):

```
// _implements() works on a JDefinedClass, 
// To get JDefinedClass we need to run _getClass() on a generated codeModel (after mapper.generate() ), 
// But What should be provided as a fully qualiflied class name for the argumanet of _getClass(),
// where or .java file isn't built yet, so the class file.

codeModel._getClass("com.foo.Bar")._implements(JsonResponseObject.class);
```